# Reference/ elementary proof of a result about projective dimension in group rings

Tags: rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra, homological-dimension

Hello- I've had to use a result that sounds like it should be well-known, but I couldn't find any references, and my proof is rather unsatisfactory.  I was hoping someone here could help!  The problem is as follows:

Let $(K,O,k)$ be a p-modular system for a finite group $G$, and that $k$ is algebraically closed.  Then $O$ is a complete discrete valuation ring with residue field $k$. For an $OG$-module $M$, 
let $O(M)$ be the projective dimension of $M$ as an $OG$-module.  Since $O$ is a (local) PID, it follows that $O(M)$ is either infinite or 1 if $M$ has torsion.  My question concerns $O(M)$ for a 
$kG$ module $M$:

In particular, is $O(M)=1$ if and only if $M$ is projective as a $kG$ module?

To hopefully persuade you that this is not trivial, consider the following.  Call an $OG$-module $P$ $\textit{weakly projective}$ if it is a summand of a module induced from the trivial group, and 
note that a weakly projective $kG$-module is simply projective as a $kG$-module. Then $O(P)=1$, again because $O$ is a PID.  It is however, possible to construct a non-weakly projective module $N$ 
with $O(N)=1$.

I can prove this, but I've had to use some rather heavy machinery- I've not so much used a sledgehammer to crack the nut, I've nuked it.  I was hoping someone could offer a more elementary proof, or 
(better) a reference?

Perhaps a more intuitive way of thinking about it is the following equivalent problem:  If $0\rightarrow P\rightarrow P\rightarrow M\rightarrow 0$ is a sequence of $OG$-modules with $P$ projective 
(and hence free as an $O$-module) and $M$ a $kG$-module, then the sequence is exact only if $M$ is projective (and hence isomorphic to $P\otimes_O k$, so that the first map in the sequence is multiplication by $\pi$, the generator of the maximal ideal in $O$.).

I hope the question is clear, and I would appreciate any insight!

Comment: I do not understand your equivalent reformulation.  What are the morphisms in the sequence P -> P -> M?  Or what do we know about this sequence?  We must know something (which is not clear to me from what you've written) if there is to be any hope that a property exclusively of M will tell us whether or not the sequence is exact.  Also, are all the P's in that paragraph isomorphic?  

Comment: Sorry, I realise I wasn't particularly clear.  My point is that any torsion module M with O(M)=1 would have a projective resolution of that form (The Ps being isomorphic follows from the fact that they would then afford the same character).  So my question boils down to whether M being kG-projective is a necessary condition for there to be such an exact sequence.  A priori, I do not assume anything else about the sequence.

Comment: I've also edited that last paragraph slightly- I hope it makes things clearer.

Comment: Thanks.  So the equivalent statement is that a kG-module M admits a resolution of that form iff M is projective as a kG-module.  Is that right?

Further up in the question, you say that O(M) will be 1 or infinity.  I'm confused.  I would expect the projective dimension of a projective to be zero, so I would expect the projective dimension of O(M) to be zero or one.  Can you clarify this?  

I should apologize in advance that, even once I understand the question, I may well not be able to help a lot in solving it.

Comment: Well, an OG-module can only be projective if it is free as an O-module (since free modules are O-free).  Hence any module with torsion (i.e. a kG-module, which is annihilated by $\pi$) must have higher projective dimension.  

Thanks for the interest!